# Pretty printing JSON with Grails Views

Tags: json, grails

Is it possible to pretty-print JSON output when using the Grails Views library for JSON output (and its template files with .gson extension)?

Background: I'm using Grails Views 1.3.0 (currently on Grails 3.1.16) for data export / rendering a complex JSON tree into a file via the JsonViewTemplateEngine (see chapter 2.11 of Grails Views [documentation](http://views.grails.org/latest/#_the_jsontemplateengine)).

I may be asking Google the wrong questions, but I haven't found a way to do this (without parsing/re-rendering the JSON output, which isn't very efficient) and most of the existing information relates to JSON converters but not to Grails JSON Views... Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You use `setPrettyPrinting` when creating the GsonBuilder:

```
public class GsonExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();

        String[] lang = {"Value One", "Value Two"};

        String json = gson.toJson(lang);

        System.out.println(json);

    }

}
```

> Configures Gson to output Json that fits in a page for pretty
>   printing. This option only affects Json serialization.

You can find documentation for it [here](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#setPrettyPrinting()).

Comment: It looks like this answer is for another library and not for Grails Views. I guess the GSON reference may be a bit confusing in my original question as it only refers to template files that use the .gson extension in Grails. I will edit the question to make the file extension more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

For Grails 4, I am doing this and then rendering the value as a regular string/variable in my GSP. Grails' GSON should work similarly.

The CSS `white-space: pre` property helps in the browser when you want to display the raw JSON.

```
def json = x as JSON
json.prettyPrint = true;
log.info(json.toString())
```